# Subgraphs hypercubes

Tags: graph-theory

$H_k$ is the kth hypercube graph.

What is the number of subgraphs of $H_4$ isomorphic to $H_3$?

What is the number of subgraphs of $H_4$ isomorphic to $K_{1,3}$? I think is $4(16)=64$.

What is the number of subgraphs of $H_4$ isomorphic to $K_{2,3}$? I believe this is zero but really sure how to prove it.

What is the number of subgraphs of $H_k$ isomorphic to $P_3$? I think is $2^{(k-1)}*k*(k-1)$?

Comment: I think you're right for $K_{1, 3}$.  For $K_{2, 3}$, are you familiar with the Hamming distance definition ?  The vertices are the $2^k$ binary strings,and you join two by an edge if they differ at one position.  I think you could try supposing there is a $K_{2,3}$ and contradict it using this definition.  Though I haven't done it.

Comment: I'll try to continue the idea by @ManuelLafond. For $K_{2,3}$. It seems the following. The graph $H_k$ contains no $K_{2,3}$ subgraph. Indeed, assume the converse. 
Let $V_2$ and $V_3$ be disjoint sets of vertices of the graph $H_k$ such that $|V_2|=2$, $|V_3|=3$, and $(v,w)$ is an edge of the graph $H_k$ for every vertex $v\in V_2$ and $w\in V_3$. Without loss of generality we can pick a vertex $v_1\in V_2$ and set it as a string $00000\dots $, and also set vertices of the set $V_3$ as strings $10000\dots $, $01000\dots $, and $00100\dots $.

Comment: Let the other vertex $v_2\in V_2$ be set as a string $x_1x_2\dots$. Since the vertex $v_2$ is joined with the vertex $10000\dots $ and $v_2\ne v_1$, we have $x_1=1$.  Since the vertex $v_2$ is joined with the vertex $01000\dots $ and $x_1=0$, we have $x_2=1$. Then the vertex $v_2$  cannot be joined with the vertex $00100\dots $, a contradiction.